# New Ubuntu User Here, How Do You Get Wifi To Work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, mac, macbook

I just started using Ubuntu on my old MacBook, and the WiFi doesn't work. When I go to the WiFi settings, it says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". I went to Software & Updates>Additional Drivers, and tried to install network drivers, but when I clicked "apply changes" it said "error while applying changes
pk-client-error-quark: Cannot download packages whilst offline (257)". Before I installed Ubuntu, I booted it off of a live USB, and the WiFi worked just fine, but now it doesn't. I can confirm that it is not a hardware problem, because when I booted into mac OS, the WiFi worked. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00ef]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at c1900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Comment: What is your exact macbook version? Also, open a terminal and type `dmesg | grep -i firmware` so we can see what network card the software is looking for. Basically you need to ensure you have the correct driver and also the correct firmware to get a mac to work. We can help.

Comment: My mac's model number is A1398. When I type it in it says this (too many chars to comment): https://drive.google.com/file/d/189GUCYfDWv1TR5uvrUXfl1S3V3mTHvz3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK then you really need an internet connection to make this easier, otherwise you will be transferring files via USB while we figure it out exactly. So if you have access to a USB dongle or can share the internet connection on your phone it will be a LOT easier.

Comment: I don't have a dongle, sorry. What's so hard about using usb to transfer files?

Comment: OK so a macbook pro 15,x probably uses BCM4355 but you need to confirm this by typing `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` in a terminal and sharing the result with us. Edit your question then copy&paste the result so the community can see it better.

Comment: Ok done. It says something about BCM4331

Comment: That's good news, I will post an answer and if you get stuck on a specific task, post a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you going however it would be much easier if you can connect to the internet using you phone or a USB dongle.
[b43 driver (Open-source) is the one you want](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)